# Is there something similar to Hashmap that preserves the ordering?

Tags: java

I have a HashMap . It looks like there is no ordering to the list.
Is there any way I can use something else that preserves the order of how they are put into the map?

Comment: (In future, please don't include the body of your question three times. Check the preview before posting.)

Comment: @JonSkeet: He was probably trying to fight the low-quality filter.

Comment: @SLaks: Quite possibly. Not that that was the best approach, of course :(

Answer (score 6):

I think you're looking for [`LinkedHashMap<K, V>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

And yes, you're right that [`HashMap<K, V>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) doesn't maintain any documented order. From the documentation itself:

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.